# Matching regex pattern in .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am using the following code in .htaccess to change the language of my website:

```
RewriteRule ^en/?(.*) $1?locale=en_GB [QSA,DPI,L]
```

So to the visitor the page appears as `mysite.com/en/index.php` but in actual fact the address is `mysite.com/index.php?locale=en_GB`.

The regex I am using is not quite right, however, because I get a 404 error when attempting to access `mysite.com/en/enquiry.php` (or `mysite.com/ru/enquiry.php`, or any other language for that matter).

Even after reading info at regular-expressions.info and Wikipedia, and using a variety of JavaScript regex helpers, I cannot work out how to get it to match `en`, `en/` or `en/dir/pagename.php` whilst ignoring any words beginning with `en` such as `enquiry` or `enquiry-send.php`.

What regular expression should I be using so that any of the following addresses work correctly (these are a few examples - page names may contain hyphens `-` or underscores `_`):

```
mysite.com/en
mysite.com/en/
mysite.com/en/index.php
mysite.com/en/enquiry.php
mysite.com/en/enquiry-send.php
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I have it working using the following expression:

```
RewriteRule ^en(/?$|/(.*)) $1?locale=en_GB [QSA,DPI,L]
```

Comment: Can't verify right now, but `^/en/(.*)$ $1?locale=en_GB`

Comment: Not sure that would work, as there may or may not be a forward slash after the `en`.

Comment: only for `mysite.com/en`; still, you can just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?locale=en_GB [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^en/([^?]*) $1?locale=en_GB [L,QSA]
```

That will match all of your test URLs, and send `en` alone to the index.php file

Comment: no problem, haven't tested it so please test before confirming this. May also want to test the addition of DPI in the square brace flags, I've never had a need for using it before, and not sure as to the effects it would have

Answer (score -1):

it's works

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/   
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) $1?lang=en_GB [L]
```

Comment: You would want to put QSA in the square braces too, so that any URL parameters get included `[L,QSA]`

Comment: in fact, the majority of the above is not going to do anything. The rewrite base is incorrect and the parameter should be locale not lang